# Centering Problem

Tags: html, css, centering

I cant seem to get this to work.

http://www.keironlowe.host56.com

What I need is the banner with the low opacity image on it to be centered no matter the resolution, Ive tried a wrapper but because the wrapper is a width of 800 it cuts of the image, i've tried margin:0 auto; and i've even tried using the  tag but it still doesnt center in higher resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the  tags in @Logan's example.  That tag is deprecated anyway.  Setting a width (not auto) and setting margin-left and margin-right to 'auto' in your stylesheet should handle the centering just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the centering and pic out of the CSS and into the HTML. the css would look like this:

```
 #banner {
background-color:#000000;
height:350px;
width:auto;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

and your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="banner">
<center>
<img src=".....">
</center>
</div>
```

That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of that `<center>` tag you have around the `<div id="banner"></div>`. You don't need it and it's deprecated.

Then, swap out your current CSS of the following block:

```
#banner {
background-color:#000000;
background-image:url(../IMG/Banner_BG.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:350px;
width:auto;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

For this:

```
#banner {
background:url("../IMG/Banner_BG.png") center #000000 no-repeat;
height:350px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Swapped out the many background attributes for the shorthand. Since you're showing the image as a background, added in the `background-position` property of `center`. This will now bullseye your image into the centre.

Comment: `width` not being needed and will stretch the DIV across the whole screen.